# draw multiple polygons from a dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib, polygon

I want to create a simple map for my stores showing the size of all the different checkouts. I have 3 different till types. One is sized 4 and the other 2 are sized 1.

e.g.

Till1 - 4

Till2 - 1

Till3 - 1

I have created a table as per the following:

Till    Size    Polygon

Till1    4        [[0,1],[0,5],[1,5],[1,1]]

Till2    1        [[1,1],[1,2],[2,2],[2,1]]

ETC

Running this code:

```
df1.iloc[0]['polygon']
```

I get '[[0,1],[0,5],[1,5],[1,1]]'

However when I try to make this into a polygon it struggles:

```
Polygon(df1.iloc[0]['polygon'], True)
```

TypeError: len() of unsized object

I think it's reading it as a string and I need to pass the individual parts somehow. I have tried using split but it's still list of strings rather than a list of lists.

Any ideas?

The final code would look similar to this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
patches = []
num_polygons = len(df1)
for i in range(num_polygons):
    #polygon = Polygon([[1,1],[1,5],[2,5],[2,1]], True)
    polygon = Polygon(df1.iloc[0]['polygon'], True)
    patches.append(polygon)
p = PatchCollection(patches, cmap=matplotlib.cm.jet, alpha=0.4)
colors = 100*np.random.rand(len(patches))
p.set_array(np.array(colors))
ax.add_collection(p)
plt.ylim([0,10])
plt.xlim([0,10])
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you created this html table yourself, can you instead simply create a list of coordinates?

Comment: Looks like you need to flatten the array of points, i.e. from `[[1,1],[1,5],[2,5],[2,1]]` to `[1,1,1,5,2,5,2,1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when I was defining it, it was a string rather than a list.

So I changed:

```
df1.iloc[i, df1.columns.get_loc('polygon')] = '({x},{y}) ({x},{y1}) ({x1},{y1}) ({x1},{y})'.format(x=x,y=y,x1=x+x1,y1=y+y1)
```

to this:

```
df1.iloc[i, df1.columns.get_loc('polygon')] = [(x,y),(x,y+y1),(x+x1,y+y1),(x+x1,y)]
```